# How to insert string into query using INSERT TO in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Hopefully a quick one, but I cant find the solution.

I have a simple query q_000 that i want to put in a line of zeroes, with a name in a column.

```
strTMP = (counter - 1) * [Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] & " - " & counter * [Forms]![f_Main]!    [PowerBinCombo] & " kW"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO q_000 (Bin, Zero1, Zero2, Zero3, Zero4, Zero5) (strTMP,'1','1','1','1','1');"
```

The strin strTMP is fine, it shows what i want in a msgbox.
I can fill the the rows with 1's, but i get syntax error on the case above.

I would prefer not to do a dbs/rst command, i want to keep it short, if possible.

Best regards, Emil.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact syntax error?

Comment: "Run-time error '3134': Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood well please try:

```
strTMP = (counter - 1) * [Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] & " - " & counter * [Forms]![f_Main]!    [PowerBinCombo] & " kW"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO q_000 (Bin, Zero1, Zero2, Zero3, Zero4, Zero5) ('" & strTMP & "','1','1','1','1','1');"
```

or even:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO q_000 (Bin, Zero1, Zero2, Zero3, Zero4, Zero5) ('" & ((counter - 1) * [Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] & " - " & counter * [Forms]![f_Main]!    [PowerBinCombo] & " kW") & "','1','1','1','1','1');"
```

Comment: Both tried, i still get the "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" :(

Comment: I rest my case - It works. I just accidently deleteted the VALUE statement when i pasted your code. THANK you very much!

Comment: No problem. I'm really glad I could help. Regards :)